# Heketi: 401 Unauthorized in a kubernetes environment

Tags: kubernetes, storage, glusterfs

I am trying to deploy glusterfs/hekti with my kubernetes environment. The deployment becomes successful, but when I try to create a PVC, I get the following error:

```
Failed to provision volume with StorageClass "scdefaultgluster": failed to create volume: failed to create volume: Token is expired
```

Now, I check the heketi logs, it says the option is unauthorized:

```
[negroni] Started POST /volumes
[negroni] Completed 401 Unauthorized in 651.285µs
```

And when I try to create the volume using `heketi-cli --user < user > --secret < password > volume create` I am able to create it successfully, so somehow the kubernetes env is doing something that i am not able to catch up on. Can you please help me figure out the issue here. TIA.

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out as the machines in the cluster had different times. Syncing the clocks solved the issue.